# Hibernate expecting "all", found 'JOIN'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting

```
QuerySyntaxException: expecting "all", found 'JOIN' near line 1, column 50 [SELECT p FROM com.rr.model.Person p FETCH JOIN p.positions pos WHERE p.id=:id]
```

exception with Hibernate. Changing 'JOIN' to 'ALL' does not help and produce following error:

```
QuerySyntaxException: expecting "properties", found 'p' near line 1, column 54 [SELECT p FROM com.rr.model.Person p FETCH ALL p.positions pos WHERE p.id=:id]
```

What's going on and how the correct query should look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is I switched syntax to 'FETCH JOIN' form the correct one: 'JOIN FETCH'. The correct query should look like this

```
 SELECT p FROM Person p JOIN FETCH p.positions pos WHERE p.id=:id
```

The correct syntax with 'ALL' looks like this:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p FETCH ALL PROPERTIES WHERE p.id=:id
```